# tr with line number

Tags: tr

This is example of `tr` output

```
user@linux:~$ tr $ '\n' <<< 'abc$def$ghi'
abc
def
ghi
user@linux:~$
```

Would it be possible to add line number to each line?

E.g.

```
user@linux:~$ tr $ '\n' <<< 'abc$def$ghi'
1. abc
2. def
3. ghi
user@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe `tr`'s output into:

```
awk '{print NR". "$0}'
```

for instance to get that numbering.

For each input record (records are lines by default), we `print` the record number (`NR`) followed by `". "` followed by the full record (`$0`) followed by the output record separator (`ORS`, newline by default).

`cat -n`, `grep -n '^'`, `nl -ba -d$'\n'`, `pr -t -n` are other ways to number lines, but they all give a different output format, not all are portable/standard and some of them (`nl`, `pr`) or implementations thereof won't work on arbitrary input as they process some characters or sequences of characters in their input specially.

Note that some `awk` implementations would also choke on the NUL character if present in the input (can't happen if using the `<<<` operator in `bash` though).

Answer (score 0):

There is also a nl (number lines) command with many options, originally intended to provide the standard references for editors of publications (don't number blank lines, headers, footers, number by page:line, etc.)
Usual standard opts are: `nl -ba`

Comment: cool. `nl` is way simpler than `awk`

Comment: But it does not give the exact output that the question asks for. `cat -n` is another option, but again, with a slightly different output format (and `-n` is non-standard).

Comment: Note that it's virtually impossible to disable that headers/footers processing portably, so `nl` can't be used to number *arbitrary* input. `nl -ba -d $'\n'` would work with GNU `nl`.